# Error: PyQt5 requires Qt v5.0 or later

Tags: 14.04, python, qt5, pyqt5

I want to install [PyQt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html) on Ubuntu 14.04.2. Once downloaded and uncompressed, I run `python configure.py` as it is mentioned on the previous link. However, it asks me to install QT 5 or later. Which thing I did.

When I come back to run the command above, I get the same error:

```
begueradj@begueradj-hacker:~/Bureau/PyQt-gpl-5.4.1# python configure.py 
Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
Error: PyQt5 requires Qt v5.0 or later. You seem to be using v4.8.6. Use the
--qmake flag to specify the correct version of qmake.
```

However, after Qt5 installation, when I run this: `qmake --version`

I get this:

```
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.6 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

How to make use of the new Qt5 version instead ? (it is installed in `/opt/qt/`)

How to resolve this ?

Comment: Qt 5 is included in the default repositories. If you run `sudo apt-get install qt5-default`, it should install the basic Qt 5 development environment and set Qt 5 as the default for `qmake`.

Comment: Following up on the comment by @saiarcot895 -- is there any reason for why you installed the PyQt libraries from upstream? Do you have specific version requirements? I mean, are you asking for support of your custom Qt installation in /opt? Because it will be hard to receive support on a non-Ubuntu installation of Qt.

Comment: @saiarcot895 sorry, i can not kiss you, you're a man :) Thank you very much, it works now

Comment: @begueradj It will install bindings for the Ubuntu packaged Qt, not for the Qt installation in /opt.

Comment: @gertvdijk thank you very much for the information

Comment: Thanks to @saiarcot895, I was able to resolve the qmake issue as described in the question but I now face an error with accepting the licence: "Found the license file pyqt-gpl.sip.
Error: Make sure you have a working sip on your PATH or use the --sip argument to explicitly specify a working sip." How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @saiarcot895 said through his comment months ago, Qt 5 is included in the default repositories. I run `sudo apt-get install qt5-default` . The problem is fixed

Comment: This did not work for me. I am also running Ubuntu 14.04. I get "Using Qt version 4.8.7 in /home/username/anaconda3/lib"

Answer (score 1):

Just so that another unfortunate soul doesn't go on the same wild goose chase, as noted by a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20290211/2734863), as of Feb 2015 you can now do

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

Worked like a charm for my script in pycharm